# Merging a tuple filled my any number of tuples in one tuple and returning that sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

First question for this Problem is: How can I call a function with a tuple of tuples, my programm should be able to handle any number of tuples.

Second question: I found a way, but with defined tuples in my code and it works, so I need a hint how to call the function with a tuple with any number of tuples in it.

My code so far:

```py
def merge(tuples):
    tuples = ((2, 3, 4), (1, 6), (5, 1, 7))
    largest_tuple = len(tuples[0])
    for i in tuples:
        largest_tuple = max(largest_tuple, len(i))
    new_tuples = []
    for i in range(largest_tuple):
        tup = []
        for j in tuples:
            if i < len(j):
            tup.append(j[i])
    tup.sort()
    new_tuples = new_tuples+tup
    new_tuple = tuple(new_tuples)
    print(new_tuple)
```

For example:

```
merge((2, 3, 4), (1, 6), (5, 1, 7))
```

return:

```
(1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 4, 7)
```

Comment: How can I call a function with a tuple of tuples, because it could be any number of tuples ? >> what does this mean, you should give some example

Comment: Why don't you just do `tuple(sorted(tuples))`?

Comment: Is the added part the desired result? Can you apply your function recursively?

Comment: @StSav012 : yes added the desired result. I don't have a recursive way....

Comment: Then check this out to flatten tuples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/8554611. You need something similar.

Comment: Oh, and use `def merge (*tuples)` to call the function as you wish, without re-defining `tuples` inside it.

Comment: The problem is you have to order them by size in positional order (top to bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use A Recursive Function:

```
merged_tuple = [] # Here is where the solution goes

    def merge(tuple_set):
        for value in tuple_set: # Looping over the current tuple
            if type(value) == tuple: # if that value is a tuple
                merge(value) # Perform the function all over again
            else:
                merged_tuple.append(value) # Add the number to the solution set
                
        return tuple(sorted(merged_tuple))
```

Comment: This code don't work unfortunately, I got a RecursionError. And like I said in the comments in the post above this one: The values need to get  ordered by size in positional order (top to bottom)
`
 tuples = ((2, 3 ,4),(1, 6),(5, 1, 7))
   returns-> combined_tuple = (1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 4, 7)
`

Comment: `[Previous line repeated 995 more times]
  File "merge_tuple.py", line 5, in merge
    if type(value) == tuple: # if that value is a tuple
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean, when you want to solve a tuple, do you want it to solve anything from `(5, (3, 2 (4, 1))) ` to `((4, 3,) 5, 2, 1).` or do you just want  the code to solve a tuple with only tuples inside of it like `((1, 4, 3), (2,5))`

Comment: Only a tuple with any number of tuples in it.

Comment: That code should work then, what type of computer do you have?